# StackNavigator, SideMenu and custom Header component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, side-menu

I'm using StackNavigator from 'react-navigation', 'react-native-side-menu' and I made my Header component (I don't want to use header from StackNavigator).
How can I fix Header? When I swipe, everything is moving including Heder.

```
const myApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});

/////////////

<View>
  <SideMenu
    menu={<Menu navigation={this.props.navigation} />}
    isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
    onChange={isOpen => this.updateMenu(isOpen)}
    navigation={this.props.navigation}
  >
    <Header />

    <View>
      ...content...
    </View>
  </SideMenu>
</View>
```